# Preview can't find fonts used in eps file generated by gnuplot

Tags: preview, font, postscript

I am trying to use TimesNewRoman.ttf as the font for *.eps files generated by Gnuplot.  I am running OS X 10.9.5 on a 2010 Macbook Pro. Here is my gnuplot script.

```
set terminal postscript eps enhanced size 5,5 font 'TimesNewRoman.ttf,20' 
set output "./test.eps"
plot sin(x)
```

When I open this file with Preview, I get the error:

> PostScript Conversion Warning
>
> Converting the PostScript file “test.eps” produced the following warnings:
> · TimesNewRoman.ttf not found, using Courier.

TimesNewRoman.ttf is an exact copy of Times New Roman.ttf. Gnuplot has problems trying to find files with spaces in the file name. So I copied the /Library/Fonts/Times New Roman.ttf to /Library/Fonts/TimesNewRoman.ttf and
~/Library/Fonts/TimesNewRoman.ttf.  I believe this trick worked when I was using OS X 10.6.8, but it appears not to work in Mavericks.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Preview's postscript conversion doesn't use Times New Roman, but you (probably) *can* use Times Roman. I'm not familiar with Gnuplot, so I'm not sure how to set fonts, but the name is "Times-Roman"

Answer (score 0):

This is still a problem six years later on macOS Big Sur 11.1.

Using `brew install gnuplot` 5.4 patchlevel 1, without any `set terminal` command, gnuplot's generated EPS defaults to the font `Time-Roman`, which Preview version 11.0 of course cannot find and replaces arbitrarily with Courier.  To make such a file displayable properly:

`sed -i -e "s/Time-Roman/Times-Roman/" my_file.eps`